# Passing JSON to ASP.Net MVC Action

Tags: asp.net, json, model-view-controller, collections

I'm trying to pass a collection into JSON object into MVC Action. I have tried almost all solutions provided on google,It does not pass data to action, please let me know what i'm missing:

AJAX Request

```
var data = [];
var questID = 100;
data.push({ QuestionTypeId: '2', QuestionId: questID, Answer: 'asdff' });
data.push({ QuestionTypeId: '2', QuestionId: questID, Answer: 'asdff' });
data.push({ QuestionTypeId: '2', QuestionId: questID, Answer: 'asdff' });
data.push({ QuestionTypeId: '2', QuestionId: questID, Answer: 'asdff' });

//var items = JSON.stringify(data);
//alert(items);
var items = JSON.stringify({ 'items': data });
alert(items);

$.ajax({
url: '/Dashboard/CreateAssessment',
data: items,
type: 'POST',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: 'json',
traditional: true,
success: function (response) {
if (response.success) {
    swal('Password Changed', response.Message, 'success');
                        window.location.href = "/Account/Management";
                    } else {
                        $("update-password").removeAttr("disabled");
                        swal('Error', response.Message, 'error');
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    $("update-password").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            });
```

Model Class

```
public class AssessmentQuestion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public string PreviousYearValue { get; set; }
    public QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action Method

```
// POST: /Dashboard/CreateAssessment
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreateAssessment(List<AssessmentAnswerModel> items)
{
        var text = items;
        return Json(new { success = true });
       // return null;
        //return RedirectToAction("Thanks", "Account");
}
```

Comment: Change the line `var items = JSON.stringify({ 'items': data });` to `var items = JSON.stringify(data);` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check follwing code with error line identified.

```
var data = [];
var questID = 100;
data.push({ QuestionTypeId: '2', QuestionId: questID, Answer: 'asdff' });
data.push({ QuestionTypeId: '2', QuestionId: questID, Answer: 'asdff' });
data.push({ QuestionTypeId: '2', QuestionId: questID, Answer: 'asdff' });
data.push({ QuestionTypeId: '2', QuestionId: questID, Answer: 'asdff' });

//var items = JSON.stringify(data);
//alert(items);


var items = JSON.stringify(data); // HERE IS THE ERROR

alert(items);

$.ajax({
url: '/Dashboard/CreateAssessment',
data: items,
type: 'POST',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: 'json',
traditional: true,
success: function (response) {
if (response.success) {
    swal('Password Changed', response.Message, 'success');
                        window.location.href = "/Account/Management";
                    } else {
                        $("update-password").removeAttr("disabled");
                        swal('Error', response.Message, 'error');
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    $("update-password").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            });
```

Please recheck your AssessmentAnswerModel with case sensitive consideration

Please mark as answer if found helpful.

Comment: Thanks - I already tried var items = JSON.stringify(data); I used this before and then commented. Ideally it should be like this only. But in controller public JsonResult CreateAssessment(List<AssessmentAnswerModel> items) it gets 0. No data

Answer (score 0):

In controller you need to pick data as an array for example

```
// POST: /Dashboard/CreateAssessment
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateAssessment(AssessmentAnswerModel[] items)
 {
    var text = items;
    return Json(new { success = true });

 }
```

I'm not sure why it happens like this but it worked like what I did.